# Computation of the global sections of a normal sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, sheaf-theory

Let $Y\subset X=\mathbb{P}^r$ be the image of the Veronese embedding $\mathbb{P}^1\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^r$. I want to calculate $dim$ $H^{0}(C,\mathcal{N}_{Y|X})$, where $\mathcal{N}_{Y|X}$ is the normal sheaf of $Y$ in $X$. My idea was to use the short exact sequence $0\rightarrow \mathcal{T}_{Y} \rightarrow \mathcal{T}_{X}\otimes\mathcal{O}_{Y}\rightarrow\mathcal{N}_{Y|X}\rightarrow 0$ but I'm not really sure about the way to proceed. Can someone give me some help? Thank you in advance!

Comment: This looks like a good start. Now a) how does your short exact sequence relate to the quantity you want to compute? b) what do you know about vector bundles (=locally free sheaves) on $Y \cong \mathbf P^1$?

Comment: I tried to pass to the associated long exact sequence in cohomology, using the vanishing of the $H^{1}$ of the tangent sheaf of $Y$ which should be isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_{Y}(2)$, in order to get a short exact sequence involving the $H^{0}$, but I'm having some troubles computing the middle element of the sequence...

Comment: Try using Euler sequence

Comment: Yes, I tried, but in the end I didn't get the right result. Maybe I made some mistakes in the computation, but I can't find them.

Comment: Dear user, did you make up this problem or was it suggested by someone?

Comment: It's the exercise 1.26 of the Harris-Morrison's "Moduli of Curves".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are almost there, so let's fill in the remaining details.

As you said in the comments, passing to the cohomology long exact sequence associated to your short exact sequence gives

$$\operatorname{dim} H^0 (Y,N) = \operatorname{dim} H^0 (Y,T_X \otimes O_Y) -3.$$

So we need to calculate the space of sections of $T_X \otimes O_Y$. As @IrfanKadikoylu suggests, we have have the Euler sequence

$$0 \rightarrow O_X \rightarrow O_X(1)^{\oplus r+1} \rightarrow T_X \rightarrow 0;$$

we can restrict this to $Y$ to get the exact sequence

$$0 \rightarrow O_Y \rightarrow (O_X(1)_{|Y})^{\oplus r+1} \otimes O_Y \rightarrow T_X \otimes O_Y \rightarrow 0.$$

(Make sure you understand why this is still exact!)

Now take cohomology; since $H^1(Y,O_Y)=0$, all that remains is to calculate the space of sections of the middle term. But $Y$ is a curve of degree $r$ in $X$, so $O_X(1)_{|Y} = O_Y(r)$, whose sections you understand.

Comment: @ Asal Beag Dubh: I guess you forgot to write $\rightarrow 0$ at the end of both sequences above

Comment: @IrfanKadikoylu: no, I deliberately didn't write them on the right; I forgot _not_ to write them on the left. :) Now fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much. In the end, my mistake was to consider the restriction of $O_{X}(1)$ to Y isomorphic to $O_{Y}(1)$ and not to $O_{Y}(r)$.